# Plot two vectors selected from two different data.frames

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of correlation values in df1. I want to select the correlation values that are above 0.3 and make a plot of the corresponding "genes" and "miRNAs" from df2 and df3, respectively. 
For instance, gene "4057" and miRNA "hsa-miR-10a-5p" has a correlation of 0.377, then I want to select that genes from df2 and that miRNA from df3 and plot the two vectors against each other.

The matrices have different sizes so I need to get the rownames from df2 and df3 to get the genes and miRNAs to plot.

df1 (correlation values)

```
df1 <-
structure(c(-0.123527914476431, -0.00191368375009113, 0.206329536015974, 
-0.0709338776700445, -0.115896333017424, -0.125478547128287, 
-0.00931326091711015, 0.0193057941898672, -0.144565138149741, 
-0.0594153240504483), .Dim = c(5L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("hsa-let-7a-3p", 
"hsa-let-7a-5p", "hsa-let-7b-3p", "hsa-let-7b-5p", "hsa-let-7c-5p"
), c("9473", "9446")))
```

df2 (genes)

```
df2 <-
structure(c(4.95596367554674, 4.83602254848161, 4.28774184754794, 
5.42319073450686, 4.99602258870066, 3.84789833077499, 4.40660838665264, 
3.90254998563245, 5.7625184441094, 3.50353293596127, 4.80461918489051, 
3.41880869529729, 5.13990627733018, 5.06752841971704, 2.54781787941398, 
5.32269972247275, 1.72108547809436, 4.23107687831885, 4.38225432253243, 
1.74793463045192), .Dim = 5:4, .Dimnames = list(c("8813", "2519", 
"2729", "4800", "57185"), c("9446", "9450", "9473", "9484")))
```

df3 (miRNAs)

```
df3 <-
structure(c(5.33977753674163, 16.7094706871338, 4.23758718121094, 
12.6275105554044, 9.04107044295747, -0.685470517077967, 16.7897917316432, 
-4.25347907370252, 13.4032906994389, 12.4040556704001, 2.51260901116279, 
16.0324845504096, 5.50096403268869, 12.0305530420621, 11.8057011378596, 
1.00715758856066, 15.6131178756706, 2.48509953100854, 11.9807372642204, 
7.93896000301356), .Dim = 5:4, .Dimnames = list(c("hsa-let-7a-3p", 
"hsa-let-7a-5p", "hsa-let-7b-3p", "hsa-let-7b-5p", "hsa-let-7c-5p"
), c("9446", "9450", "9473", "9484")))
```

Comment: Please show what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not at all sure that this is the kind of graph that you want but it does plot the vectors of gene and miRNA with correlation greater than 0.3  against each others.

```
library(ggplot2)

inx <- which(df1 > 0.0, arr.ind = TRUE)
res <- data.frame()
k <- 0L
for(i in 1:nrow(inx)){
  x <- df2[, inx[i, 2]]
  y <- df3[, inx[i, 1]]
  k <- k + 1L
  tmp <- data.frame(vector = k, gene = x, miRNA = y)
  res <- rbind(res, tmp)
}
res$vector <- factor(res$vector)

ggplot(res, aes(gene, miRNA)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = vector))
```

[image]

Following the OP's request here is a solution with one plot per vector of correlations.

```
ggplot(res, aes(gene, miRNA)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = vector)) +
  facet_grid(vector ~ ., scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, however I would like separate plots for each correlation. Split into facets. In my example, that would be 3 separate plots in a facet_grid or wrap. And using the gene-names and miRNA-name on the axis.

Comment: @user2300940 Done. I have kept the original.

Comment: Hi, there was a bug in my example. df1 and df2 and df2 have different sizes, so that getting the positions like you did do not work. We would need to get out the rownames from df2 and df3 by saving the colnames and rownames from df1. Also, I want to plot the correlations between the rows, not the columns, like this: df3[, inx[i, 1]]. Please see updated post.

Comment: @user2300940 How can you get vectors from `df2` and `df3` based on `df1` if none of the row and column names match?

Comment: A colname in df1 will match a rowname in df2. A rowname in df1 will match a rowname in df3. Updated. Treshhold value needs to be >0.

Comment: @user2300940 Done, but `df3` had one row too many. I fixed that in the question's posted data. (It would have 6 values of miRNA for 5 genes only.)